# Understanding returning Derived class with generic parameter as base interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have a situation where I want to create an instance of a class depending on the implementation of the interface passed in as a parameter.

```
public interface IFooParameters
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public interface IFooParametersAdditional
{
    int AnotherProperty { get; }
}

public class FooBarParameters : IFooParameters
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    public int Bar { get; set; } = 42;
}

public class FooBazParameters : FooBarParameters, IFooParametersAdditional
{
    public int Baz { get; set; } = 55;
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; } = 99;
}

public interface IFoo<in TFooParameters>
    where TFooParameters : IFooParameters
{
    void DoStuff(TFooParameters parameters);
}

public class Bar : IFoo<FooBarParameters>
{
    public void DoStuff(FooBarParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Baz : IFoo<FooBazParameters>
{
    public void DoStuff(FooBazParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Another : IFoo<FooBazParameters>
{
    public void DoStuff(FooBazParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IFooFactory
{
    IFoo<IFooParameters> GetInstance(IFooParameters parameters);
}

public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    public IFoo<IFooParameters> GetInstance(IFooParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.Id == 1)
            return new Bar(); // *** compiler error

        if (parameters.Id == 2)
            return new Baz(); // *** compiler error

        return new Another(); // *** compiler error
    }
}
```

`// *** compiler error` is:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type `'Bar'` to `'IFoo<IFooParameters>'`.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'm not sure why I get this, as I thought derived implementations *should* (I would have thought) implicitly convert to their bases as `Bar : IFoo<FooBarParameters>`, and `FooBarParameters : IFooParameters` and this works (not bringing in generics):

```
public interface IBar { }
public class BarBar : IBar { }

public class Test
{
    public IBar Thing()
    {
        return new BarBar();
    }
}
```

The basic idea behind what I'm hoping to accomplish is, there are two potential implementations of `IFooParameters` to pass into the `FooFactory`, depending on the type and some validation, return an instance of `IFoo<IFooParameter>` - I only care about returning the interface, as the underlying API is the same between all implementations of `IFoo<IFooParameters`, though one implementation requires an additional property through `FooBazParameters`.

I'm pretty new to generics, so I'm not sure if what I'm attempting to do is just completely wrong, or if I'm just missing something in the implementation.  But any help and/or explanation to what's going on is appreciated.

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjyLS7

Slightly changed with cast:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZFQjCn

Comment: I don't get an error when I compile your first block of code. You need to post a proper repro.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Just copy-pasting the code gives me the same errors, as I would expect, given the code (there's no way it could possibly be allowed to compile).

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah I'm not sure how you're getting a successful build, even the first fiddle I attached has a compiler error.

Comment: @Servy Ah... I didn't select enough of the code when I was copy-pasting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compiler allowed you to convert a `Bar` instance to `IFoo<IFooParameters>` then you would be able to call `DoStuff` on that returned value passing in a `FooBazParameters` instance as the parameter, but the `Bar` instance is only allowed to take in `FooBarParameters` instances.  The only way to prevent you from being able to use the `Bar` instance in an invalid way is to prevent that conversion from being valid.

Comment: ah, that makes sense!  Is there any way to accomplish what I'm attempting to do?  (asside from drop the factory and just have the client new up the `IFoo<...>` impls directly?)

Comment: @Kritner Given that it never makes sense for you to treat different implementations of the interface differently, it doesn't even make sense for you to have an interface in the first place (either that or you should redesign your program so that you *can* treat the instances of the interface interchangably).

Comment: Yeah seems that'll have to be my route.  At least I now understand ***why*** it doesn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kritner If you want more formal explanation, you are basically trying to make your generic type parameter both covariant (`out`) and contravariant (`in`), which is basically impossible. You can take a look here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835318/672018